# Can you trade on Steam without Steam Guard enabled?

Tags: steam

I am a CS:GO/Game trader and would like to know if I can trade when my steam guard is disabled?

Comment: Why would you want to disable steam guard?

Answer (score 4):

You can trade with other users without Steam Guard, but your trade will be held back for 15 days! But you can't create steam market offers in this period.

If you are using the Steam mobile authenticator, you can complete your trades immediately. However, if you activate the mobile authenticator for the first time for your account, the first 7 days you still have the 15 days penalty.

But I really recommend to use the mobile authenticator it provides way more control and security for your steam account!

Comment: I can't be the only one who finds it to be a huge pain in the ass.  Sure, it's more secure, but I'm not _that_ worried about security.  There should be some way to decide that you want the authenticator disabled without having that terrible 15 D waiting period.  It doesn't really seem fair to force people to go through extra hoops if they don't want to (especially if you didn't even have a phone).

Comment: You'll think different after you got scammed.

Comment: In my personal case I don't really have a high value inventory or anything.  I'm saying the volume of trades/value I do I'd be willing to absorb the risk of losing it altogether.  I don't like the 2 stage verification for what I get out of it